# My subview doesn't autoSized after a rotation

Tags: xcode, ipad, rotation, autoresize

I'm trying to make a simple app on iPad. For now I only display full screen pictures in a custom view. My problem is that my view doesn't autoSized when the iPad rotates...the rotation works perfect but the size of my images are still the same.

My application is based on [this](https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform) because I wanted this effect when I switch pictures. Basically, the view that make the effect is `FlipView` that inherit form `GenericAnimationView` which inherit form `UIView`. There's also `AnimationFrame` that inherit from `NSObject` which is required to display 1 animation cycle. Finally, there's `AnimationDelegate` that inherit from `NSObject` which handle callbacks from transform operations.

Here is my `AnimationViewController`

```
    #import "AnimationViewController.h"
    #import "FlipView.h"
    #import "AnimationDelegate.h"

    @implementation AnimationViewController

    @synthesize flipView2;
    @synthesize panRecognizer;
    @synthesize panRegion;
    @synthesize imageBluehound,imageDoggie,imagePointy,imagePurpGuy,imageRedDog,imageWoof;

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
            step = 0;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    /*
    // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
    - (void)loadView
    {
    }
    */

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [flipView2 release];
        [panRecognizer release];
        [panRegion release];

        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onBackButtonPressed:)];

        // memorisation des imagesx
        imageBluehound = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bluehound.gif"];
        imageDoggie = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Doggie.gif"];
        imagePointy = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pointy.gif"];
        imagePurpGuy = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PurpGuy.gif"];
        imageRedDog = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedDog.gif"];
        imageWoof = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Woof.gif"];


        animationDelegate2 = [[AnimationDelegate alloc] initWithSequenceType:kSequenceControlled
                                                               directionType:kDirectionForward];
        animationDelegate2.controller = self;
        animationDelegate2.perspectiveDepth = 1000;

        self.flipView2 = [[FlipView alloc] initWithAnimationType:kAnimationFlipHorizontal
                                                           frame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
        animationDelegate2.transformView = flipView2;

        [self.view addSubview:flipView2];


        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imageBluehound backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];
        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imageDoggie backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];
        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imagePointy backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];
        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imagePurpGuy backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];
        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imageRedDog backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];
        [flipView2 printText:@"" usingImage:imageWoof backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] textColor:nil];


        self.panRegion = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:panRegion];

        self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
        panRecognizer.delegate = self;
        panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    }

    - (void)onBackButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    - (void)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {
        switch (recognizer.state) {
            case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
                break;
    //        case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: // for discrete recognizers
    //            break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed: // cannot recognize for multi touch sequence
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
                // allow controlled flip only when touch begins within the pan region
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(panRegion.frame, [recognizer locationInView:self.view])) {
                    if (animationDelegate2.animationState == 0) {
                        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
                        animationDelegate2.sequenceType = kSequenceControlled;
                        animationDelegate2.animationLock = YES;
                    }
                }
            }
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
                if (animationDelegate2.animationLock) {
                    switch (flipView2.animationType) {
                        case kAnimationFlipVertical: {
                            float value = [recognizer translationInView:self.view].y;
                            [animationDelegate2 setTransformValue:value delegating:NO];
                        }
                            break;
                        case kAnimationFlipHorizontal: {
                            float value = [recognizer translationInView:self.view].x;
                            [animationDelegate2 setTransformValue:value delegating:NO];
                        }
                            break;
                        default:break;
                    }
                }
            }
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled: // cancellation touch
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
                if (animationDelegate2.animationLock) {
                    // provide inertia to panning gesture
                    float value = sqrtf(fabsf([recognizer velocityInView:self.view].x))/10.0f;
                    [animationDelegate2 endStateWithSpeed:value];
                }
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // use this to trigger events after specific interactions
    - (void)animationDidFinish:(int)direction 
    {
        switch (step) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            default:break;
        }
    }

    - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
        {
            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            {
                NSLog(@"landscape left");
                self.flipView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"landscape right");
                self.flipView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            }
        }
    }


    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return YES;
    }

@end
```

And here the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FlipView;
@class AnimationDelegate;

@interface AnimationViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

    // use this to choreograph a sequence of animations that you want the user to step through
    int step;

    //the controller needs a reference to the delegate for control of the animation sequence
    AnimationDelegate *animationDelegate2;

    BOOL runWhenRestart;

}

//@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *boutonMenuGlissant;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageBluehound;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageDoggie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imagePointy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imagePurpGuy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageRedDog;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageWoof;

@property (nonatomic, retain) FlipView *flipView2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *panRegion;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;

- (void)onBackButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (void)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

// animation delegate will notify the controller when the animation frame has reached a position of rest
- (void)animationDidFinish:(int)direction;

@end
```

I saw in other posts that they talked about the autoSized mask but I couldn't make it...

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the struts and strings of your views/images. After clicking on the image, go to the size tab of the utility inspector. The example next to "autosizing" will show what the view will look like as the frame changes. Turn on/off the red connectors and arrows to make the image look the way you want when the orientation changes.

Comment: I don't get it all...where do I do that? I don't have a `.storyboard`

Comment: Click on the image view you want to modify in your xib file. Then press Command-Option-5. This will bring up the size inspector. In the box that says "Autosizing" you can toggle the red arrows and connectors to change how the view resizes when you rotate the device. Also make sure the "Mode" in the Attributes Inspector (Command-Option-4) is set to "Scale to Fill" for your image

Comment: I don't have such thing as the size inspector...I guess it needs to have a `.storyboard`

Comment: It looks like everything is being done programmatically. I'm not exactly sure what to do but possibly try adding a method that would change the size of the images depending on the orientation. Put it in your `if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))`

Comment: yeah exactly. Thats what I've finally done...that's a bit annoying but it works. I've put my code in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`